# Trying to build export to csv by passing dynamic cursor to function

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I am trying to build fixable function to export data form any table of user choose with any number of columns of user choose to `csv` file I searched and found their is away like making package for the type,... etc. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629802/can-i-pass-an-explicit-cursor-to-a-function-procedure-for-use-in-for-loop)...and another way by using dynamic cursor which I choose , but I am getting error as shown below

I tried to use CURSOR that has RETURN type However, only REF CURSOR without RETURN type can be OPEN" by an embedded dynamic OPEN statement.

**NOTE** this procedure is not complete yet since I need to make `UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.x)`; fixable too I working on it but I need to get out of this error any suggestion are really appreciated

> ```
> [Error] PLS-00320 (9: 13): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00382 (27: 22): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> [Error] PLS-00320 (29: 29): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (30: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (31: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (32: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (33: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (34: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (35: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> [Error] PLS-00320 (36: 44): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXPORT_TO_CSV_NEW (P_SQL_STMT   IN VARCHAR2,
                                              P_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                              P_CREATED_BY IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS 

   TYPE CUR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR; ---  RETURN WAREHOUSE%ROWTYPE;
   CUR  CUR_TYPE;
   CUR_RG   CUR%ROWTYPE;
   SQL_STMT VARCHAR2 (4000);

   FILETYPE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   FILENAME VARCHAR2(256);
   DIRECTORYNAME VARCHAR2(1280) := 'SRJD_DEFAULT_TEMP_DIR';

   ERR_CODE VARCHAR2(64);
   ERR_MSG  VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

 SAVEPOINT SETP1;

   FILENAME := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || '_WAREHOUSE.CSV';
   FILETYPE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (DIRECTORYNAME,FILENAME,'w',32767);
   SQL_STMT := P_SQL_STMT;

   OPEN CUR FOR SQL_STMT;
    LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO CUR_RG;
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE,        CUR_RG.PRODUCT_ID);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.CLASSIFICATION_ID);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.PRODUCT_DESC);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.MANUFACTORY);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.BOX_COUNT);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.BOX_COST);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.BOX_ITEM_COUNT);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.ITEM_COST);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.MEASUREMENT_UNIT);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.REVENUE_PCT);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.ITEM_PRICE);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.TOTAL_ITEM_QUANTITY);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.TOTAL_COST);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.NOTES);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.CREATED_BY);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.CREATED_ON);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.UPDATED_BY);
            UTL_FILE.PUT (FILETYPE, ',' || CUR_RG.UPDATED_ON);

           UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE (FILETYPE);
         EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;       
    END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (FILETYPE);
   CLOSE CUR;

   RETURN (1);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    ROLLBACK TO STEP1;

    ERR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    ERR_MSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1024);

    SQL_STMT := F_INS_ERROR_LOG(SYSDATE,              --P_ERROR_TIME,
                                P_CREATED_BY,         --P_USER_ID,
                                'EXPORT_TO_CSV_NEW',      --P_PROGRAM_UNIT,
                                NULL,                 --P_ERROR_LOCATION,
                                'FileName '||FILENAME,--P_KEY_DATA_DESC,
                                ERR_CODE,             --P_ERROR_CODE,
                                ERR_MSG);             --P_ERROR_MSG';
RETURN -1;

END EXPORT_TO_CSV_NEW;
/
```

Comment: You might want to start with this open source code that exports Oracle SQL statements to CSV: https://github.com/VentechCMS/utilities/blob/master/data_dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
CUR_RG   CUR%ROWTYPE;
```

You are trying to define a record as a `rowtype` of a `REF CURSOR` variable - which is not permitted.

You are passing a query as procedure argument. So, it cannot be initialized as a CURSOR inside your procedure.You can only `OPEN` it as `REF CURSOR.`

One way to resolve this would be to declare the `CURSOR` within this  procedure using the query and not to pass it as an argument. But, If you need to pass query as an argument, then you could define a `RECORD TYPE` with all the required columns which you would fetch.

```
TYPE prodrec IS RECORD
(
 PRODUCT_ID           WAREHOUSE.PRODUCT_ID%TYPE,
 CLASSIFICATION_ID    WAREHOUSE.CLASSIFICATION_ID%TYPE,
 PRODUCT_DESC         WAREHOUSE.PRODUCT_DESC%TYPE,
 MANUFACTORY          WAREHOUSE.MANUFACTORY%TYPE,
 BOX_COUNT            WAREHOUSE.BOX_COUNT%TYPE,
 BOX_COST             WAREHOUSE.BOX_COST%TYPE,
 BOX_ITEM_COUNT       WAREHOUSE.BOX_ITEM_COUNT%TYPE,
 ITEM_COST            WAREHOUSE.ITEM_COST%TYPE,
 MEASUREMENT_UNIT     WAREHOUSE.MEASUREMENT_UNIT%TYPE,
 REVENUE_PCT          WAREHOUSE.REVENUE_PCT%TYPE,
 ITEM_PRICE           WAREHOUSE.ITEM_PRICE%TYPE,
 TOTAL_ITEM_QUANTITY  WAREHOUSE.TOTAL_ITEM_QUANTITY%TYPE,
 TOTAL_COST           WAREHOUSE.TOTAL_COST%TYPE,
 NOTES                WAREHOUSE.NOTES%TYPE,
 CREATED_BY           WAREHOUSE.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
 CREATED_ON           WAREHOUSE.CREATED_ON%TYPE,
 UPDATED_BY           WAREHOUSE.UPDATED_BY%TYPE,
 UPDATED_ON           WAREHOUSE.UPDATED_ON%TYPE
 );
```

Then declare a variable of this record type.

```
CUR_RG prodrec;.
```

With this change, your `FETCH` statement would work normally.

And, I see that you are using rollback inside the `EXCEPTION`. This makes no sense as  you are not performing any DML operation.

Comment: as I said I am trying to build fixable function to export data form any table of user choose with any number of columns of user choose to csv file and at your answer table are statics thank you in anyway for suggestion my friend :)