# How to pass cursors result as a parameter in procedure

Tags: plsql, cursor

I have a cursor which returns 2 rows :

```
Attach name         Attach MIME type
----------          ---------------
abc.pdf             application/pdf
xyz.pdf             application/pdf
```

Now I want to pass these values into a procedure  (** marked parameters below).

```
send_smtp_mail(p_to => 'xyx@xyz.com',p_from => 'xyx@xyz.com',p_subject => 'TEst',p_text_msg => NULL,p_attach_name=> ********,p_attach_mime=> *********)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a cursor, then there should be a loop in which you'd use value returned by that cursor. Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur in (select attach_name, attach_type from some_table)
  loop
    send_smtp_mail
     (p_to          => 'xyx@xyz.com',
      p_from        => 'xyx@xyz.com',
      p_subject     => 'TEst',
      p_text_msg    => NULL,
      p_attach_name => cur.attach_name,         --> this
      p_attach_mime => cur.attach_mime_type     --> and this
    );
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: THanks for your reply. Though it will not solve my issue. Actually I need to call that procedure just once and I have to pass the result of cursor in that 1 call. I am nt sure how I can do that. May be array or something ? Once I calll that procedure that I need to process the results of the reords fetched by this cursor...

Comment: Well, that depends on what exactly your code does & looks like. You could, for example, apply LISTAGG to results returned by query and pass *concatenated* attach name & mime type to SEND_SMTP_MAIL procedure. Question is: what will that procedure do with those values? Did you handle it?

Comment: I have just elaborated the question in my comments..there I have written a snippet of code...about what my procedure does after getting the values . Can you please check and help.. I think that if I use an array then the probelm will get resolved...but I am not sure how to do that..

Comment: It seems as if the whole thing should be done in a single procedure, not two. This one is just a "wrapper" of the SEND_SMTP_MAIL. The main problem is - what? To send mails with multiple attachments?  If so, have a look at this blog: http://www.oracletool.com/blog/?p=64 Comments below it suggest that it works (I didn't try it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to change the `send_smtp_mail` function, you can pass the cursor as a parameter (replace parameters `p_attach_name` and `p_attach_mime` with `p_attachment_cursor`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_smtp_mail(..., p_attachment_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
  attach_name ...
  attach_mime ...
BEGIN
LOOP
FETCH p_attachment_cursor INTO attach_name, attach_mime ...
EXIT WHEN p_attachment_cursor%NOTFOUND;

-- process data as needed
END LOOP;

CLOSE p_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: But where should I open the cursor in this case. I will have to declare the cursor in one proc and then pass it when calling the 2nd proc...right..Now where should I open the cursor, in the 2nd proc ?and then fetch the rows ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Maybe creating a package as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647869/5226711 is a solution for you?